# asp.net web service how to restrict access of some methods for some users

Tags: asp.net

in asp.net web service can we restrict some methods to some users.
For example, userA should access methodA and methodB, But userB only access methodB.
Can we do this? if yes then how?

Comment: What kind of web service?

Answer (score 0):

u caN use `PrincipalPermission`

here is the sample how to implement .All user(`UserB,UserA,Admin`) can access this method)

```
 [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "UserB")]
 [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin")]
 [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "UserA")]

 public bool Add(Item item)
       {

}
```